# How to display image ALT under image?

Tags: images

In each post, I have ~10 images with alt. How to display under each image ALT as a visible text?

Comment: The text in the `alt` attribute is meant to be a textual equivalent (and _alternative_) for the image. Why would you want to show that?

Comment: Because I want to show people this text, my readers want it.

Comment: WordPress supports a _description_ field which is far better suited for this, and you can use it without any extra hack.

Comment: The 'caption' field for each image usually is set (by the theme) to display below the image. If you copy the 'alt' text into the 'caption' field it should display just like you want.

Comment: I have 70 000 images, it's impossible...

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="logo" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B5aXOWzIMAA1DoS.png" alt="flower">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var alt_name=$('.logo').attr('alt');
    alert(alt_name);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please format your code and also add explanation?